# Where is the data stored in when using glBindBuffer() and glBufferData() functions?

Tags: opengl

From some books,I can get that `glGenBuffer()` generate a buffer object,`glBindBuffer()` will allocate a block of memory for the buffer object,then `glBufferData()` is gonna send the data to the memory.So the memory `glBindBuffer()` is graphics memory or cpu memory?

Comment: graphics memory (gpu)

Comment: Thank you again,but this is another question,I will be very thankful if you can spare your time.The example codes use glGenBuffer(1,&vboVert), glBindBuffer(GL_ARRY_BUFFER,vboVert),glBufferData()......and then ,glGenBuffer(1,&vboColor), glBindBuffer(GL_ARRY_BUFFER,vboColor),glBufferData().....In this case,the codes bind two buffer objects to GL_ARRY_BUFFER in turn.Accroding to the caption of glBufferData, when then second buffer object is bound to GL_ARRY_BUFFER,the former data of vboVert transported to graphics memory should be cleared,but the codes work good.Where do I misunderstand the part?

Comment: There are 2 different buffer object and each has its own data store (`vboVert`, `vboColor`). [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) creates and initializes a buffer object's data store for the buffer object which is currently bound to the target `GL_ARRY_BUFFER`. This binding is a global state.

Comment: I get it,Thank you!